# Как создать читалку для android?

Tags: java, android

Хочу написать читалку, но не имею ни малейшего понятия куда двигаться. Как я понимаю, нужно получить файл, допустим, fb2, открыть его и отобразить на экране пользователя в форматированном виде. Как можно отформатировать этот самый файл? Точнее, какой метод этим занимается? Быть может, есть какие-нибудь туториалы? Я искал, но ничего не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно стоит для начала прочесть книгу по Android, да и по Java не помешает.

Ну а если у вас достаточно компетенции, чтобы разобраться в исходниках под android, то есть OpenSource читалки, вот например: https://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/
Можно заглянуть в код и посмотреть как она работает

для этого вам понадобится установленный svn, и вот команда загрузки репозитория читалки:

```
svn checkout http://ebookdroid.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ebookdroid-read-only
```